# Ad Choice not showing in Native Banner ad

Tags: banner-ads, native-ads, google-ad-manager

For some ad providers we are not receiving the ad choice icon. As per google the ad without ad choice icon is violation.
So what is the best solution to handle such case where the provider is not sending the ad choice icon?